# Nginx-extras installation on debian 8

Tags: linux, debian, nginx

I have a problem with intallation of nginx-extras on a debian 8 server 8.11. The 'apt-get install nginx-extras' return me:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nginx-extras : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.6.2-5+deb8u6) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The installed nginx version is: 1.15.12 Below the apt sources.list:

```
deb http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb-src http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib
deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/ jessie nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/ jessie nginx
```

Any idea how solve the problem?